# Rows to columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot, transpose

I have the following main table:

```
order_id    unique_order_id   article_price
    1             1A                100
    1             1B                200 
    1             1C                300
    2             2A                100
```

and I would like to have the following result:

```
order_id   article_priceA    article_priceB   article_priceC
    1            100                200              300
    2            100                null             null
```

I have found a solution by doing self joins of the main table for each unique_order I have (I will max have 4 different unique orders per order_id (A,B,C,D), however I would like to know if there is a better way to do this?

my current solution goes something like this:

```
select 
a.order_id, 
a.article_price as article_priceA,
b.article_price as article_priceB, 
c.article_price as article_priceC

from main a 
left join main b on b.order_id=a.order_id and right(unique_order_id,1)='B' 
left join main c on b.order_id=a.order_id and right(unique_order_id,1)='C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select order_id,
    max(case when right(unique_order_id, 1) = 'A' then article_price end) as article_priceA,
    max(case when right(unique_order_id, 1) = 'B' then article_price end) as article_priceB,
    max(case when right(unique_order_id, 1) = 'C' then article_price end) as article_priceC
from main
group by order_id;
```